# Laravel is returning view with 404

Tags: php, laravel, web

web.php

```
Route::get('/jobs/{id}/edit', 'JobController@edit')->name('job.edit');
```

then html page:

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('job.edit', [$job->id])}}"><button class="btn btn-dark">Edit</button></a>

    <a href="{{ route('jobs.show', [$job->id, $job->slug])}}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Apply</button></a>
</td>
```

The jobs.show is working, so that's fine

If I click on the edit button the URL is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs/41/edit
```

controller

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Job;
    use App\Company;
    use App\Http\Requests\JobPostRequest;
    
    class JobController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $jobs = Job::all()->take(10);
            return view('welcome', compact('jobs'));
        }
    
        public function edit($id) {
            $job = Job::findOrFail($id);
            return view('jobs.edit', compact('job'));
        }
        
        public function show($id, Job $job) {
            return view('jobs.show', compact('job'));
        }
    }
?>
```

folder where the edit view is located:

resources -> views -> jobs -> edit.blade.php

Does anyone has an idea why I get page 404?

Comment: `findOrFail($id)` takes an `id` and returns a single model. If no matching model exist, it throws an 404 error

Comment: Show us Job model and db table.

Comment: See comments below. Thanks for replying my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually if the error is 404, there is something wrong with your code in web.php or the link in your blade. Try using this:

```
<a href="{{url('jobs')}}/{{$job->id}}/edit" ><button class="btn btn-dark">Edit</button></a>
```

Basically, try changing the href link to something like above and see if it works